# Add buttons to layout with a View

Tags: android

I'm trying out the Finger Paint API demo and I'm trying to add buttons to it. I have included

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.triopsys.imosandroid.ViewControllers.SignatureViewController$MyView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my layout xml, but I can't add buttons on the top or bottom of this view;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.triopsys.imosandroid.ViewControllers.SignatureViewController$MyView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to the Layout wrapping your buttons. IIRC the default is vertical, so it's stacking 2 buttons with zero width on top of each other.

Comment: The default orientation is [horizontal](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).

Comment: So it is. My apologies. I'll fix the post once I confirm the following: I'm not at my dev machine, but there also seems to be an issue with OPs `View` sizing, which is set to `match_parent`, and then the `LinearLayout` it sits in is set to `wrap_content`, so what height does it take? The full screen?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are getting no errors:**

then I guess the problem is with the Buttons' width values. Change it to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly doesn't work? I tried this layout, it compiles and correctly displays.

If "doesn't work" means "my custom view is not takes the whole screen" then remove `linearLayout2`. In any case it is redundant and may be deleted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.triopsys.imosandroid.ViewControllers.SignatureViewController$MyView" />

</LinearLayout>
```